# JFrog artifactory + xray docker compose installation is failing

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

I am trying to install JFrog using docker compose file. I followed the steps mentioned here https://jfrog.com/xray/install/

When I run the config script, PostgreSQL container keeps on restarting and the installation fails with the below message

> ./config.sh
>
> Beginning JFrog Platform Trial Pro X setup
>
> Validating System requirements
>
> [WARN] Running with 2 CPU Cores. Recommended value: 3 Cores
>
> Installation Directory found in .env. Skipping prompt
>
> Creating third party directories (if necessary) stat: illegal option
> -- c usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]
>
> Attempting to seed PostgreSQL. This may take some time. Error response
> from daemon: Container
> 9924cc25d606159c131c4091d2676cdb6920f5ca2151155bb0cbe5aac6c9b28b is
> restarting, wait until the container is running

Docker log on the container:

```
docker logs 9924cc25d606159c131c4091d2676cdb6920f5ca2151155bb0cbe5aac6c9b28b
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed and will be released shortly. Please expect this in 7.15, I will confirm once this is actually released.

9th Feb 2021: We have created a patch 7.12.8 which fixes this issue, among others. Hope you can confirm and use it. Thank you.